# TYPO3 10.4.16 cli commands missing?

Tags: cron, command-line-interface, typo3-10.x

checking which cli commands my installation of TYPO3 10.4.16 offers with `php typo3 list` in directory `/var/www/html/typo3_src/typo3/sysext/core/bin` I only get very few commands offered (output of command see below).

E.g. the scheduler extension is installed and works fine when commands are executed manually. Therefore I would expect to at least get the command `scheduler:run` offered in the cli list.

The Installation is non-composer as the server is behind heavy firewalls.

Has anyone experienced similar behaviour?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben

Result of list-command:

```
TYPO3 CMS 10.4.16 (Application Context: Production)

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  help             Displays help for a command
  list             Lists commands
 language
  language:update  Update the language files of all activated extensions
 upgrade
  upgrade:list     List available upgrade wizards.
  upgrade:run      Run upgrade wizard. Without arguments all available wizards will be run.
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

When calling the typo3 script, the CWD has to be the root of your TYPO3 Installation while executing the command.

This works:

1. navigate to root folder of TYPO3
2. `php typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3`

This doesn't work:

1. navigation to /typo3/sysext/core/bin/
2. execute php typo3